# When I user Django to create a user account, can the account be created in Kerberos automatically?

Tags: python, django, kerberos, django-authentication

I'm using the Django framework to make a website. When I create a user in Django, how do I get that user to be created in Kerberos?

Answer (score 0):

[use](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/) [signals](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Signals).

What do you looking for is [`post_save()` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save), just send the User model to it as sender ;)

See the [django-registration](http://www.bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/wiki/Home) for some example specially about user registration,